# How to update a column of all rows with unique incremented value ordered by time and date?

Tags: sql, postgresql, queue, window-functions, row-number

I have a queue to maintain in postgres database, I need to keep track of position of the entries based on when they entered the queue (time & date), now at some point in my application, i need to remove one or more entry from database, in that case I need to realign the positions of the entries with respect to the time they joined, for instance here is my table structure
[image]
now lets suppose we delete the entry of position 1, in that case the the position of entry with the position value 2 should update to 1 and that of 3 to 2 respectively, I'm trying to do it the following way using row_number()

```
update waitingvisitor upd
set position = a.row_number
FROM (
SELECT "queueId", row_number() over(order by "timeJoined")
from waitingvisitor
ORDER BY  "timeJoined"
) as a
where upd."queueId" = a."queueId";
```

but all that does is strange , i can't seem to get my head around it why it updates all the rows something like this
[image]

now what i want is , based on timeJoined field the values for column "position" should be updated accordingly, the one who joined earliest should be given higher priority for instance. What's going wrong in here?

Answer (score 1):

Alright that has been sorted out, all i had to do is compare primary key ids instead of queueId columns in the here clause , Godamnt, the reason I think is the column queue id carries same value for all the rows.

```
 update waitingvisitor upd
 set position = a.row_number
 FROM (
SELECT "queueId", row_number() over(order by "timeJoined")
from waitingvisitor
ORDER BY  "timeJoined"
) as a 
where upd."id" = a."id";
```